# Applescript remote control volume

Tags: macos, applescript, sound-volume

Wondering how to turn up the volume on my computer from another computer.

```
set volume 4 of machine remMachine
```

doesn't work
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to remotely control a Mac, say your desktop machine, you must first set it up for commands to be sent to it. To do this, launch **System Preferences** > **Sharing** on the Mac you want to control. Click the box next to **Remote Apple Events**, and set user restrictions if you need to.

Next, you will need the IP address. In **System Preferences**, switch to **Network** and locate your machine’s **IP address**. It should be something like, **192.168.0.3**. Copy that address to proceed to the next step. You can also use the machine’s Bonjour name which can be found at the top of the **Sharing** pane in System Preferences. Its address will be spelled similar to this one: "**smith-nancy-computer.local**"

Now from another Mac, create your applescript like this:

```
tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://192.163.0.3"
set volume 4
end tell
```

---

#### Sidenote:

*Unfortunately I don't have a second Mac to test this on, so if anyone can improve this answer if it doesn't work, please feel free to make changes or add comments.*

Comment: Well, its address won't be **"smith-nancy-computer.local"**, but it'll be the name of your computer, spaces replaced with dashes (and other symbols removed/replaced) and end with _.local_. (This is for @Shrey Somaiya)

Comment: IPv4 addresses have **4** octets, **not 5** as you've shown!

Comment: @Brick of course that won't be the name of the computer, but it's an ideal example just like the IP address is not going to be exact, its an example. I never said "It will be", instead I opted for suggestive language "...similar to this one"

Comment: @user3439894 good catch !

Comment: Yes @Danijel-JamesW I'm just helping you further explain...

Comment: I think i should delete this post, the reason it didnt work int he first time is because i had the syntax wrong. Thank you for all the help guys!

Comment: Please leave the question here on Stackexchange. It's good for historical reference and then other users might find a use from this information too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! :)
I have figured out the solution. Turns out my original script was 

    `set remMachine to "eppc://user@1.2.3.4.local"
using terms from application "Finder" 
    set volume 10 of machine remMachine
end using terms from`

Thank you for all the help :)
The solved script was:

      `set remMachine to "eppc://user@1.2.3.4.local"
    tell application "Finder" of machine remMachine
        set volume 10
    end tell`